# gson JSON to Java -- json property has . or - in it

Tags: java, gson

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1.I have a json reponse as

```
String Content = 
"{
   "region":{
      "state.code":"TX",
      "country-code":"USA"
   }
}";
```

2.I want to convert this Json Object into Java Object.I have this Java class to convert

```
public class Region{
   private String stateCode;
   private String countryCode;
            public String getStateCode ()
        {
            return stateCode;
        }

        public void setStateCode (String stateCode)
        {
            this.stateCode = stateCode;
        }

           public String getCountryCode ()
        {
            return countryCode;
        }

        public void setCountryCode (String countryCode)
        {
            this.countryCode = countryCode;
        }
}
```

3.My problem is Java doesnt allow . or - in variable name.Which doesnt allow json string to map to Region java class object giving null .

```
gson.fromJson(Content, Region.class);
```

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
Can anybody please help me in this?
I have tried @SerializedName annotations but it is not working.

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?

Please provide any additional information below.

Comment: _I have tried @SerializedName annotations but it is not working._ Why not?

Comment: Also, your root JSON is not mappable to a `Region` instance. Your root JSON is an object that contains a `Region` object.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `@SerializedName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to map this JSON

```
{
   "region":{
      "state.code":"TX",
      "country-code":"USA"
   }
}
```

to an instance of type `Region`. That JSON is a JSON Object which contains a pair with name `region` and a value which is a JSON Object. That JSON Object has two pairs, one with name `state.code` and JSON String value `TX` and one with name `country-code` and JSON String value `USA`.

You can't map that to a `Region` object. You have to bypass the root's pair named `region`.

Create a encapsulating type

```
class RegionContainer {
    private Region region;
    // the rest
}
```

and map that

```
gson.fromJson(Content, RegionContainer.class);
```

`@SerializedName` will work for your fields.

```
@SerializedName("state.code")
private String stateCode;
```